# How to apply styles to both a class and a media query in SASS?

Tags: css, sass, dry

On mobile devices, my header must be always sticky. On other devices, it must be sticky only when it has the class `sticky`:

```
.header {
  &.sticky {
    position: fixed;
    // other styles
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .header {
    position: fixed;
    // other styles
  }
}
```

I want to write my styles once only (DRY principle), is there a way to achieve that with `SASS`?

It might look like:

```
.header {
  @include media_600,
  &.sticky {
    position: fixed;
  }
}
```

.. or something similar, but I don't know what.

Comment: There might be a way to somehow archive this using SASS, but DRY does not mean, that you are never allowed to duplicate certain peaces of code. Because regardless of the solution, it's going to be a lot harder to understand what's going on in your code (think about KISS principle). Also, regardless of what you do, the compiled CSS code will look like your example anyways. What you could do, is move the `@media only screen and (max-width: 600px)` inside the `.header` class, that at least removes a little redundancy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are on the right track. Creating a mixin with a content block (https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/mixin#content-blocks) will allow you to add styles without having to specify the selector again and also will enable you to reuse it throughout your code.

```
@mixin mobile {
  @media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    @content;
  }
}

.header {
  &.sticky {
    position: fixed;
  }

  @include mobile { 
    position: fixed;
  }
}
```

If you only want to write the CSS property once then you can do this.

```
@mixin sticky-header {
  position: fixed;
}

.header {
  &.sticky {
    @include sticky-header;
  }

  @media only screen and (max-width: 600px) { 
    @include sticky-header;
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello, while a code-only answer is fine, it's recommended you include a brief description of your solution and why you've made the choices you've made.

Comment: @HenryWoody, thanks for the feedback. I have added an explanation for the solution.

Comment: Uh, but you still need to write the styles twice... Perhaps I should have been more explicit in my question: my goal is to write them once instead of twice.

Comment: @drake035 I updated the answer, let me know if this is what you want to achieve.